# knife vault rotate all keys -- tries to rotate deleted vault

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm currently getting the error 
`ERROR: ChefVault::Exceptions::KeysNotFound: xxxx/xxxx_keys could not be found` during a `knife vault rotate all keys` command.

The vault in question was deleted some time ago and so this should no longer try and rotate the key.

Does anyone know of a way to refresh the list of vaults for knife to rotate the keys on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Verify if vault was removed completely, run `knife data bag show <vault name>`. There may be some leftovers (`<item name>` data bags) on the list, you can remove it by running `knife data bag delete <vault name> <item name>`.

Comment: Hi, that wasn't my problem, there are no traces of the vault. It seems to be stored in a cache somewhere

Comment: There is no vault cache afaik, everything is kept in data bags.

Comment: [Rotate all keys](https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/78d6aa6bf3448466d3cf586a811277d16ed27ff9/lib/chef/knife/vault_rotate_all_keys.rb#L37) is pretty simple, it looks for pair of `<vault_name>` and `<vault_name>_keys` data bags and it [regenerates keys](https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/2187b5b0e721ef40a30a69a58cc5e6f73d925a94/lib/chef-vault/item.rb#L172). Maybe you have data bag which looks like vault for chef-vault or your vault structure is broken/damaged.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the vault structure?